# Use NSArrayController with nested NSMutableArrays (Cocoa Bindings Question)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a NSArrayController with following Object:

```
@interface AdressCard : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString* name;
    NSString* street;
    NSMutableArray* tasks;
}
```

I have a simple GUI with an NSTableView to display the first two keys and I want to have a second NSTableView to display the content of the MutableArray (tasks) for the selected item of the first TableView.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean AddressCard, right? ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selection` property of the array controller, instead of `arrangedObjects`, for the second table view.

What you're doing is called a master/detail layout; the documentation has [a tutorial on it](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html).